# R merge fitted values and residuals of lm model to original dataset

Tags: r, join, merge

How to merge horizontally two data frames with equal rows and no key for join?

I want to merge fitted values and residuals of lm model to original dataset. Is it possible without adding index column first to original dataset? Does R store data in dataframe in random order similar to Microsoft SQL Server? Or the order of original data set and fitted values is preserved?

Comment: merge without column to merge on? Do you just want to bind the two data.frames? If so, `cbind()` is probably what you need.  If not, please provide a minimal reproducible sample of input and desired output.

Comment: Also, check out `broom::augment()`